# No detection of a touchScreen Button event in a modal window on Android

Tags: android, events, button, javafx, touchscreen

I made a Javafx application that works fine on PC. Now, I try to transfer it to Android Smartphone. To do that, I use JavaFXPorts (Gluon), with Eclipse and Gradle.

Now, I am stuck with a very simple example:

```
void showPopUp() {
     Button button = new Button("Action do do")); 
     HBox.setMargin(button , new Insets(10, 30, 10, 30));

     button .setOnAction(e -> {
            actionToDo();
        });

     Scene scene = new Scene (button, 100, 200);
     Stage stage = new Stage();
     stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
     stage.setScene(scene);
     stage.show();
}
```

Have you an idea of the reason?

### Thanks

Here is the ***whole code*** with:

- a periodic task (it works fine)
- a delayed task (it works fine)
- a button "btn" that displays the modal PopUp. The touchScreen on it works fine and allows to go to the PopUp
- the PopUp with 2 buttons boutonPopUpA and boutonPopUpB that are added  to the HBOX boutonsMenuPrincipal
- and a stage with its scene "connected to" boutonsMenuPrincipal

**In the popUp, boutonPopUpA and boutonPopUpB are displayed but inactive** (No generated trace on a touchScreen)

```
 package com.gluonapplication;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class GluonApplication extends Application {

    private int nbAppuiToucheSetOnAction = 0;
    private int nbAppuiTouchePopUp = 0;


    static long BDTapplication = 110;
    static long nbBDT = 0;
    static long t0 = System.currentTimeMillis();


    /********************************************************/
    public static void periodicProcessing(String str) {
        nbBDT++;
        traceWithSystemTime("periodicProcessing of " + str + " / nbBDT: " + nbBDT);
    }

    /********************************************************/
    public static void traceWithSystemTime(String comments) {
            long t =  System.currentTimeMillis();
            long deltaT =t - t0;
           System.out.println("time - t0: " + t0 + " /  t: "+ t + " / detaT: " + deltaT + " ms --- " + comments);
    }

  /********************************************************/
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World sur Android! ");

        // A PERIODIC TASK
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                for (int i=0; i < 10; i++) {
                    periodicProcessing("timer plus");
                }
            }
        };
           final ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
           service.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnable, 0, BDTapplication, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

// A DELAYED TASK
        int TASK_DELAY = 1000; // ms
        TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    periodicProcessing("timer task done");
                }
            }
        };

        new Timer().schedule(task, TASK_DELAY);


        AnchorPane root = new AnchorPane();
         root.setVisible(true);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);


        // *********************** Button
      // btn works fine
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("setOnAction 1");

        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                nbAppuiToucheSetOnAction++;
               traceWithSystemTime("SETonACTION: nbAppui = "+ nbAppuiToucheSetOnAction);
                showPopUpMenuPrincipal();
         }
        });
        HBox.setMargin(btn, new Insets(10, 30, 10, 30));

        VBox zoneBtn= new VBox();
        VBox.setMargin(zoneBtn, new Insets(30, 5, 1, 10));
        zoneBtn.getChildren().add( btn);
        zoneBtn.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

         root.getChildren().addAll(zoneBtn);


         primaryStage.setTitle("Title");


        // ************************************* DISPLAY
        root.requestFocus();
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Test4");
        primaryStage.setFullScreen(true);
        primaryStage.show();

       traceWithSystemTime("End of test");

    }

    /*************************************/
void    showPopUpMenuPrincipal(){
    traceWithSystemTime("Beginning of  showPopUpMenuPrincipal");
    Button boutonPopUpA = new Button("setOnAction 2a");
    boutonPopUpA.setOnAction(e-> {
        nbAppuiTouchePopUp++;
       traceWithSystemTime("Action sur setOnAction 2a: nbAppui: " + nbAppuiTouchePopUp);
    });
    Button boutonPopUpB = new Button("setOnAction 2b");
    boutonPopUpB.setOnAction(e-> {
        nbAppuiTouchePopUp++;
       traceWithSystemTime("Action sur setOnAction 2b: nbAppui: " + nbAppuiTouchePopUp);
    });

    HBox.setMargin(boutonPopUpA, new Insets(10, 30, 10, 30));

    VBox zonePopUp= new VBox();
    VBox.setMargin(zonePopUp, new Insets(30, 5, 1, 10));
    zonePopUp.getChildren().add( boutonPopUpA);
    zonePopUp.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);


    Stage stagePopUpMenu = new Stage();
    stagePopUpMenu.setTitle("Title");
    stagePopUpMenu.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);

    HBox boutonsMenuPrincipal = new HBox();
    boutonsMenuPrincipal.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    boutonsMenuPrincipal.getChildren().addAll( zonePopUp, boutonPopUpB);

    Scene sceneMenu = new Scene(boutonsMenuPrincipal, 400, 250);

    stagePopUpMenu.setOpacity(0.8);
    stagePopUpMenu.setResizable(false);


    stagePopUpMenu.setScene(sceneMenu);
    stagePopUpMenu.show();
    traceWithSystemTime("End of  showPopUpMenuPrincipal");
}

    }
```

---

**And my build gradle:**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.0.0-b10'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

mainClassName = 'com.gluonapplication.GluonApplication'

jfxmobile {
    android {
        applicationPackage = 'com.gluonapplication'
        manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
        androidSdk = 'C:/Users/pascal/AppData/Local/Android/sdk'
        resDirectory = 'src/android/res'
        compileSdkVersion = '23'
        buildToolsVersion = '22.0.1'
    }
    ios {
        infoPList = file('src/ios/Default-Info.plist')
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you describe what "stuck" means? Do you have an error, the popup doesn't show...? Can you post the required code to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Can you post your build.gradle file as well?

Comment: Here is the build.gradle file

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the jfxmobile plugin version. Many things have been fixed and updated since the 1.0.0-b10 version (from a year and a half ago).

Currently the [version](https://bitbucket.org/javafxports/javafxmobile-plugin) is 1.3.2. It is not only the plugin, but the mainly the javafxports [version](https://bitbucket.org/javafxports/8u-dev-rt/overview) that the plugin includes.

If you use the Gluon plugin on your favorite IDE, selecting a Single View project you will get the minimum project template and a valid `build.gradle` file.

This is an updated build script:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.3.2'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases'
    }
}

mainClassName = 'com.gluonhq.testtouch.TestTouch'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:4.3.0'
}

jfxmobile {
    downConfig {
        version = '3.2.0'
        plugins 'display', 'lifecycle', 'statusbar', 'storage'
    }
    android {
        manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
    }
}
```

You can add all your code to the BasicView, deploy it on mobile and test it.

I've just done it and everything works fine: the task runs fast, and the buttons are responsive.

Using JavaFXPorts it's not recommended creating a second `Stage`. You can use a `Dialog` (either built-in JavaFX dialog or Gluon Mobile dialog) instead.

You can test Gluon Mobile library for free, you will get only a nag screen at startup.

Anyway, you can remove the Gluon Mobile library (just remove `com.gluonhq:charm:4.3.0` from dependencies), and you'll have to port back `MobileApplication` to a regular JavaFX `Application` and remove the BasicView class (mostly as you have now).