# Real Time processing on a touchScreen in JavaFX for Android

Tags: android, events, javafx, real-time, touchscreen

When I add a button in an AnchorPane (not in a PopUp like in this other test [No detection of a touchScreen Button event in a modal window on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41702674/no-detection-of-a-touchscreen-button-event-with-setonaction-on-android-smartph)), I have a kind of real time problem.

The test conditions are:
I often touch the same button. If the deltaOfTime between two touchScreen is greater than 1 second, the processing under the button is taken into account. When the deltaOfTime is lower, there is no action

I use JavaFXPorts (Gluon), with Eclipse and Gradle.

```
public void start() {
     Button button = new Button("Action do do")); 
     HBox.setMargin(button , new Insets(10, 30, 10, 30));

     button .setOnAction(e -> {
            actionToDo();
        });

     Scene scene = new Scene (button, 100, 200);
     Stage stage = new Stage();
     stage.setScene(scene);
     stage.show();
}
```

An idea? Does that mean that JavaFxPorts takes a lot of time to get events?

My application is a video game. Therefore, the final aim is to use the touchScreen for shooting, for instance, ... with deltaOfTime < 500 ms

Thanks

Comment: What is your phone and Android version?

Comment: smartphone "Archos Diamond S" with Android 5.1 and its kernel version: 3.10.65  ....... And Gluon Tools 1.0.0 with Gradle IDE 3.7.0. JavaFXPorts is only related to Gluon. Do you agree?

Comment: Tools? you mean the jfxmobile plugin? It's actual version is 1.3.2, and you can run it with or without the Gluon Mobile library. Update it and try again

Comment: I got the versions Gluon Tools and Gradle IDE by clicking, under Eclipse, on Project - help -  Installation details, that provides the installation list. 
In the list, it is not explicitly mentioned the jfxmobile install.Is it normal?
In fact, the jfxmobile version is defined in the dependencies section of the build.gradle file. In this file, is it enough to modify the jfxmobile version from 1.0.0 to 1.3.2 for getting the more recent plugin?
Do you think that my (basic) problems encountered when I used of timelines and the button events can be solved by only modifying the jfxmobile version?

Comment: If I use the Gluon Mobile library, I should see it in the Java Build Path windows of my Eclipse project, isn't it? But I don't see it here. Is it is mentioned elsewhere? 

When you say "you can run it with or without the Gluon Mobile library", you differentiate the jfxmobile and the Gluon mobile. Are they the same aim consisting in providing javafxports for Android, iOS, ...?
If yes, what is the most finalized? I say that because I use, for instance, other JavaFX notions like PathTransition, RotateTransition, ParallelTransition ...that work fine on desktop.

Thanks a lot for your response

Comment: Check the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41702674/no-detection-of-a-touchscreen-button-event-in-a-modal-window-on-android/41760352#41760352) about the build configuration. And yes, most of the problems are solved probably updating the plugin version.